ADFS - OWA - ECP automatically signs out when loging from custom IdP
i have a problem.
Im logging into adfs with Keycloak as an IdP, everything works well. Im redirected from Keycloak to ADFS and then im getting redirected to OWA the to the ECP with signout request.
Token is sent to LS and /ls is redirecting to logoff /ecp/auth/TimeoutLogout.aspx
My relying party settings:
SsoLifetime : 480
TokenLifetime : 60
Both for test.com/ECP and test.com/OWA
Additionally when logging only using /adfs/ls/IdpInitiatedSignon.aspx im getting redirected to keycloak and then redirected to succesfully logged in page on adfs, where i can see that im logged in.
What can i provide to describe problem better? How should i configure Active Directory, maybe there is a problem?
